# What is the preparation before painting oil over waterborne alkyd paint?

Tags: painting

We painted some cabinets with a single coat of a waterborne alkyd product, but now want to paint them over with a straight oil finish (for our own reasons).  What is the preparation for doing this to insure a proper bond?

Comment: Test a hidden small area first. Oil over any latex base may cause an alligator skin effect and ruin your cabinets.

Comment: Will sanding or priming over the waterborne product prevent this from happening?

Comment: I cannot say for sure. The rule of thumb is latex over oil is fine, oil over latex disaster.

Comment: True for latex paints, but what of waterborne alkyds? Alkyds are the chemical base for most oil based paints. I would think oil base over such a product would be OK provided the base layer is fully dried and an appropriate surface prep is preformed, but I don't know really. Interesting question once it is fully understood. OTOH, there's very little reason to use oil based paints any more.

Comment: I was reading about Water borne color alkyds. Even though it is oil solvent free, it is not a true latex. I think you can use an oil over it.  There are only two manufactures I found, BenMor and SherWill. I bet they can give you an accurate answer.